# Can I send my location in an imessage directly from the messages app?

Tags: ios, messages, maps

I know I can go to the Maps app, and then click on the pin for my current location, and then select to share it, and then pick to send a message (vs. an email etc.)

**But I can't find any way to send my location from the messages app, the way I might send a photo.**

Which is silly - **how often are you hanging around in the maps app when you want to tell someone where you are?**   It makes sense when you're sending a location where you aren't, say the restaurant you'll meet at tomorrow, but you'd think a solid percentage of shared locations are "here's where I am", and in almost all of those cases, you're starting in the message app, not the map.

A I missing anything?

Comment: [Find My Friends](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/find-my-friends/id466122094?mt=8) tries to do this holistically - letting you create a temporary event where you explicitly share with one or a group your location.

Comment: I'm rolling this the wrong direction since the new interface is changed quite a bit and most of the answers here just don't apply. It's a great question for 2011 so I don't think merging it makes sense. It should remain / documenting what was and pointing to the new interface IMO. Ping me here or on [meta] if anyone wants to change / discuss the close direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS 8 or later, in iMessage once you have your conversation with the contact(s) you wish to send your location with, tap "Details" and then tap "Send Location".

Comment: Great answer - even though this showed up a while ago, I never found it, most likely because it's unintuitive; most "details" are about the *contact*, not me, so I never thought to look there!

Answer (score 3):

*Edit:* Sorry, I skimmed a bit and missed that you figured this part out already. I don't believe it can be done directly from the Messages app. In conceptual terms, the iOS model for data sharing is typically such that you send data from an app, but the "sending apps" generally can't grab data from elsewhere. This is true for most things except photos, *i.e.* you can send a contact from the Contacts app, but you can't directly attach one from the Messages app.

---

*Original post:*

You can do this by tapping the blue arrow (blue *i* on an iPad) on any location (dropped pin, current location), and tapping **Share Location**. It will give you the option of sending via email, Message or Tweet. Your recipient will get sent a contact with a maps url and address.

Answer (score 0):

MultiTask to maps - drop your pin, share back to SMS/email.

I suppose some twitter apps will let you geotag a post, but there's no way to pin an arbitrary SMS or email other than starting from Maps.

Answer (score -1):

You can search for a location and when the red pin is on the map you can click it and choose to share location. I think this works